# Swift using completion handlers to lock a view in one controller to reflect in another

Tags: ios, swift, completionhandler

It would seem I have a timing issue with what I am trying to achieve.

I am looking to have the following implemented.

1. User arrives on screen (view controller) and is ready to 'Lock' there selection
2. Lock/unlock icon is on the upper right in the navigation bar
3. User clicks the icon to Lock
4. UIAlert box displayed confirming that the user want to lock their selection
5. User confirms
6. User is presented a different view that allows them to enter a 'PIN'
7. If they hit cancel, dismiss the PIN view controller and the lock state remains as unlocked
8. If they click 'Submit', dismiss the PIN modal view controller
9. The icon on the top right needs to change to a 'Locked' icon

Everything seems to be working with the exception that the icon and state does not update properly since it would seem that once the user gets present the PIN modal view controller the code just keeps getting executed in which the 'Lock' status stays as 'Unlocked' since the user has not entered their PIN and hit submit which would change the 'Lock' status?

Can completion handlers 'suspend' the state until the user gets displayed the modal window, followed by entering a PIN and then Submits their PIN... and remember the user can also hit cancel if they wish to not lock anymore for what ever reason?

Comment: are you talking about view controller's completion handler? which is called right after a view controller is presented?

Comment: it would be better if you show your code so that people didn't have to guess what precisely is going on

Answer (score 1):

In `FirstViewController`, you can add on completion on lock/unlock navigation item click,

```
func lockOrUnlock() {
    let pinVC = PinViewController()
    pinVC.onCompletion = { [weak self] (isPinChanged) in
        //change the lock/unlock icon based on isPinChanged flag
        //if true then update the status else revert the status to prev one
        }
    let pinVCNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pinVC)
    pinVCNavController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    self.present(pinVCNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In `PinViewController`, return the flag value as `true or false` based on user's choice to submit or cancel the action,

```
var onCompletion: ((Bool) -> Void)?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let cencelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction))
    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cencelButton
}

@IBAction func submitAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.onCompletion?(true)
}

func cancelAction() {
    self.onCompletion?(false)
}
```

Comment: So this in essence has replaced the use of `protocols` over `completion handlers`? I ask because currently I am utilizing a protocol to pass back the information to the parent VC from the child VC. But it would seem the code just keep moving forward, not waiting for the input from the user, so the status never changes to locked 'in time' for the code to recognize that the value changed.

Comment: I would venture to say in your approach the completion handle will wait, for however long the user takes to provide input/action before it changes the locked status based on 'Submit' or 'Cancel' being clicked and the modal view being dismissed.

Comment: you can use protocol as well, completion is just one option to achieve the solution

Comment: I used the protocol and as I stated it seems the code just keeps moving forward which by the time the uses 'Submits' or 'Cancels', the code on the main tread has executed the Firebase update using the initial `LockStatus` as false.